# Why JSON Object Serialization is needed or important sending in ajax call to the server?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have seen at several places developers are using `JSON.stringify(data)` while making an Ajax call to the server for the serialization of post data in JSON string, but why it is needed ?

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    contentType: "application/json",
    complete: callback
});
```

Comment: If you want to send JSON data, you need to JSON-serialise it. I'm unclear why that is a question. Can you elaborate why think it may *not* be necessary?

Comment: Maybe the OP isn't confused about the need for serialization but the method. As i have seen people stringify it whilst others do not and set the `json` flag to true so jquery does it for us.

Comment: hi @deceze I have used several times without serializing JSON data and it works fine, so why need to serialize here!

Comment: If you don't serialise it to JSON, it'll be automatically serialised via URL-encoding. If you want JSON, you need to serialise it to JSON instead (or do the same via any number of alternative methods jQuery offers).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Several modern frameworks are capable to directly bind JSON data structures to their model businesses, this allows for a incredibly fast and easy relationship between client and server data models.

This way you can work feely on your client side with js objects, on the moment that you send data to the server via AJAX, you just stringify these objects to allow the server end to understand them, and in an automatic way your server will be able to translate that info to your server data classes, without further interaction needed (of course, you will need defined classes that are compatible with your client model data structures).

Answer (score 2):

You have to encode the data using *some* method in order to send it over HTTP.

JSON is a standard format that supports common data structures like arrays. This lets you describe most kinds of data that you would want to send.